# Is is safe to edit the jsp in a .WAR file

Tags: java, war

I need to edit a jsp in a .WAR file to correct a spelling error. Is it safe to do so? Or does the war file have some magical setup that is broken as soon as I change anything?

I've read some on various forums about it and it seems ok, but it would be nice with confirmation from someone who knows.

Comment: To sum up, Yes you can (tested it in our test environment). But it isn't a good idea. I only did it because I didn't know what revision of the code was in production, and I also changed in the source for future deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally wouldn't edit a jsp inside a deployed war file. I would prefer to edit the jsp on my development machine, possibly test it, rebuild the war file with the updated jsp, and redeploy it on the application server.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, the source contained changes that I shouldn't deploy yet, and I don't know what revision is in production... But I tested in our test environment and it worked fine. Also changed the source for future deployments. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it should be okay to edit the jsp in the .war, provided you also make the same edit in the original jsp, else you would lose the change when you re-create the war file (i presume your source code is checked into some repository)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, the source contained changes that I shouldn't deploy yet, and I don't know what revision is in production... But I tested in our test environment and it worked fine.